# Receiving data from word press

Tags: wordpress, web-services, receiver

I created custom PHP file in WordPress to send order data to an accounting server via its web service.

Now I need to take amount of goods from that accounting server and update the stock  of each product.

I do not access that server, and they don't have any document for their web-service.

I tried to find some info about using web service to do this, but the only thing that I got was to send (not receiving) data of a WordPress site via web service.

This is my code that send order details to accounting server:

```
<?php
require_once('../wp-config.php');
require_once('../wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-order.php');

$today =  new DateTime();
$today->setTime( 0, 0, 0 );

$args = array(
    'limit' => 9999,
    'return' => 'ids',
    'date_completed' => $today,
    'status' => 'completed'
);

$query = new WC_Order_Query( $args );
$orders = $query->get_orders();

$url = "http://###.###.###.###:8081/Service1.svc/InsertInvoice";

foreach( $orders as $order_id ) {
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $order_date_completed = $order->get_date_completed();
    if (false === strtotime($order_date_completed)) {
        echo 'Invalid date for order number '.$order_id.'<br>';
    }else {
        $order_date_completed->setTime( 0, 0, 0 );
        $diff = $today->diff( $order_date_completed );
        $diffDays = (integer)$diff->format( "%R%a" );

        if($diffDays == 0){

            $items = $order->get_items();
            $InvoiceInfo = array();

            foreach( $items as $item ){

                $product = $item->get_product();

                $item_sku  = $product->get_sku();
                $saleType  = substr($item_sku, 1, 2);
                $item_code = substr($item_sku, 3, 8);
                $user_id   = substr($item_sku, 11, 6);

                $data2 = array(
                    'CustomerCode' => $user_id,
                    'SaleTypeNumber' => $saleType,
                    'ItemCode' => $item_code,
                    'Quantity' => $item->get_quantity(),
                    'Fee' => $product->get_price(),
                    'Discount' => 0,
                    'Addition' => 0,
                    'Tax' => 0,
                    'Duty' => 0,
                    'Rate' => 1,
                    'StockCode' => 5,
                );
                array_push($InvoiceInfo,$data2);
            }

            $postdata = json_encode($InvoiceInfo);
            $ch = curl_init($url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
            $result = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: We can't answer your question here without more information. Can you share some more details like what web service, what ecommerce plugin, a code example of that you've tried. Your question is also unclear on where you're trying to update the stock. Nearly every ecommerce plugin manages inventory if you have the option selected.

Comment: Actually it doesn't matter which web-service, easier is better. I need to update instock field of each product in woocommerce via some web-service according the information which have sent to my WordPress site.

Comment: I guess my question is why not do it the same function as you send the order data? I'm assuming your trying to get the product inventory information from the accounting site, in which case we'd need the name of the accounting site so we can check their API docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to send data to WooCommerce, you can use WordPress REST API custom endpoint that can receive data from anywhere.

But, as you didn't provide the name of the accounting server or even any information about the accounting app, you have to check if it is possible to send data from your accounting app to a webhook (with a service like Zapier).